# equality testing in for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, equality

I'm currently writing a program to calculate arctangent using a Taylor Series sum. The centre part of the code is the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    firstval=sum; //sum=0
    sum=sum+sumterm(x,i);   //calculate the sum
    if(fabs(sum-firstval)<delta) //delta=10e-6
    {
        s=i;
    }
    else s=0;
}
```

How I think this code is working: 'sum' is initialised to 0, meaning that 'firstval' is as well. The program then calculates the Taylor series value for a particular value of i, and adds it on to the sum. Then, as 'sum' and 'firstval' are different, the magnitude of their difference can be calculated - as the loop proceeds, firstval is the previous value of the sum, and then in the loop, sum becomes its next term. Then when the difference between them is sufficiently small, and the condition is matched, the value of i for which that has happened is saved to an integer s, which is otherwise 0.

However, the program currently only produces 0, or says that the sum has only converged at n-1. I've spent quite a while playing around with different configurations of the code and can't work out why it's doing what it is. I'm still a newbie to this programming thing, so any help is welcome. Sorry if this post is unclear, I know that I haven't included the rest of the program, but I've had a quite long and tiring day. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that `10e-6` is `1.0E-5`.  You might want to use `break;` after setting `s = i;` so you don't go round the loop again.  As it is, you get to `i == n-1`, and the delta is small enough that you set `s = i;` again and that's why you see what you see.

Comment: You presumably want to end the loop if your `if` condition is true, so you should put a `break` after the `s=i`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a while loop instead. The condition to exit the while loop could be:

```
while (fabs(sum-firstval)>delta)
```

Otherwise, other suggestions (using a break after variable `s` has been assigned value of `i`) work too.